How to confirm Erasure of Generic Types in Java
Oracle documentation explains that Generic Type is erasured by the compiler.
I don't know exactly what I understood...
I'd like to know what I'm missing.
public class GenericErasure<T> {
   private T target;
   public GenericErasure() {}
}

According to the document, I think the combination of the above codes will change as follows.
public class GenericErasure {
   private Object target;
   public GenericErasure() {}
}

However, if you look at the actual compiled file, the Generic Type parameter is still there.
public class GenericErasure<T> {
   private T target;
   public GenericErasure() {}
}


It's erased as the point of usage, not at the point of declaration. A class retains its generic type parameters, as you can see by the existence of the reflection method getTypeParameters. If you instantiate that class somewhere GenericErasure<String> test = new GenericErasure(), then that bytecode will have no evidence that String was the argument.

Think about it - if bytecode for a class definition had no info that the class is generic, how would a library class work? Libraries are shipped as bytecode. If your class was imported from a library and you tried to make a new GenericErasure but the type params had been stripped, there would be no way for your compiler or IDE to know whether or not it expects them.
